# Transposing cells in a loop using VBA in excel

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I'm trying to copy cells from one sheet(in rows) and paste them in another sheet in rows(basically transposing it). I wrote the code but could not get around the paste cell and the pastespecial command. The length of copied cells vary by each row so how do i make it select dynamically and paste the same way? As of now I'm thinking to paste a specific length and delete the blank rows at the end.  Please see the code below. It would be awesome if anybody can give me an input or idea. Thanks!!

```
Sub Data_Sort_Test()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim rng As Range, row As Range, rowd1 As Range, cell As Range
Dim bidtype As String
k = 1
lastrow1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To lastrow1
bidtype = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "A").Value 

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
lastrow2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For j = 1 To lastrow2
If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "B").Value = bidtype Then

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "K")).Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Cells(j, "C"), Cells(j, "L")).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste 'Special Transpose:=True
'k = k + 1
End If
Next j
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "but could not get around the paste cell and the pastespecial command" mean? Did you get an error - if so what was it? Did it not behave the way you expected - if so what happened?

Comment: If you are trying to transpose, flip from horizontal to vertical, why are you trying to paste a horizontal range to a horizontal range?

Comment: @CHill60 I meant I was not able to write the code for the transposing it. I get a 1004 runtime error.

Comment: @ScottCraner my intention was to flip it. but i'm pasting it horizontally just for now. I will change it. Do you have any ideas. I mean what would be the range so that in the next iteration the cells in the range get update from the previous copied cells?

How do I share my data set so that It will give you guys an idea?

Comment: You can link to a picture on any image site.

Comment: @ScottCraner here is the link for the excel file. Please have a look. Thank you!!
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxNW23K23hUGNzh1RjZycFJnV2c

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know if it works:

```
Sub Data_Sort_Test()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim rng As Range, row As Range, rowd1 As Range, cell As Range
Dim bidtype As String
Dim tWs As Worksheet

Set tWs = Sheets("Sheet3")
With Sheets("Sheet2")
k = 1
lastrow1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To lastrow1
    bidtype = .Cells(i, "A").Value

    lastrow2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    For j = 1 To lastrow2
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "B").Value = bidtype Then

            .Range(.Cells(i, "B"), .Cells(i, "K")).Copy

            tWs.Range(tWs.Cells(j, "C"), tWs.Cells(j, "L")).PasteSpecial 'Transpose:=True

        End If
    Next j
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i
End with
End Sub
```

I removed all the `.Select` and `.Activate` and replaced them with the proper parentage directly.  This will speed up the code and makes it easier to read.

Comment: I was working on it and was able to flip it but i have a problem with the rows.count command. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

@Scott I have put the transpose, but somehow the rows.count has a problem. What do you think??

```
Sub Data_Sort_Test()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim rng As Range, row As Range, rowd1 As Range, cell As Range
Dim bidtype As String
Dim tWs As Worksheet

Set tWs = Sheets("Sheet3")
With Sheets("Sheet2")
k = 1
lastrow1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To lastrow1
bidtype = .Cells(i, "A").Value

lastrow2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & **strong text**Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
For j = 1 To lastrow2
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "B").Value = bidtype Then

        .Range(.Cells(i, "B"), .Cells(i, "K")).Copy

        tWs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        tWs.Range("B1").Delete shift:=xlUp

    End If
Next j
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Also I believe you cannot paste just values and transpose at the same time.  It does not work that way.  Its all or nothing with transpose.

Comment: @ScottCraner There isn't any error it compiles properly, but while pasting it the length of the cells(row.count) is not correct when the loop begins as row.count before entering the loop is different than the one inside.